# Is there a way to display the variable names in an array?

Tags: swift, variables, swift2, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to use an array and would like to return, not the variables in the array's values, but the actual names that were appended. Is there any way this is possible in swift? I have already tried:

`print(array.description)`

Which just returned the values in curly brackets. Does anyone know hot to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after - can you include an example. Have you tried just `print(array)`?

Answer (score 2):

No. Once the value of the variable has been copied into the array, there is no record of what variable originally held the value. If you want this information, you need to track it yourself.

Comment: Seems logical. Thanks for the quick response!